# Definition of Tensor Product of Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

I am really struggling to understand several parts of the definition of tensor product given in my lecture notes:

**Definition of the tensor product**
*Denote by L the free A-module with a basis consisting of elements l$_{m,n}$ indexed by elements of M x N. So an arbitrary element of L is a finite sum $\Sigma$ a$_i$l$_{m_i,n_i}$ with a$_i$$\in$ A, m$_i$$\in$ M and n$_i$$\in$ N. Let K be the A-submodule of L generated by elements:
l$_{m_1+m_2,n}$ - l$_{m_1,n}$ - l$_{m_2,n}$;
l$_{m,n_1+n_2}$ - l$_{m,n_1}$ - l$_{m,n_2}$ ;
l$_{am,n}$ - al$_{m,n}$;
 l$_{m,an}$ - al$_{m,n}$
(for all a $\in$ A, m $\in$ M and n $\in$ N ).
Denote T = L/K. The image of l$_{m,n}$ in T , i.e. the coset l$_{m,n}$ + K
is usually denoted by m $\otimes$ n.
Since L is generated by l$_{m,n}$, the module T is generated by m $\otimes$ n,
i.e.
T = {$\Sigma$ a$_i$m$_i$$\otimes$n$_i$ : a$_i$ $\in$ A;m$_i$ $\in$ M; n$_i$ $\in$ N }

These satisfy relations:
(m$_1$ + m$_2$) $\otimes$ n = m$_1$ $\otimes$ n + m$_2$ $\otimes$ n;   (am) $\otimes$ n = a(m $\otimes$ n); m $\otimes$ (n$_1$ + n$_2$) = m $\otimes$ n$_1$ + m $\otimes$ n$_2$;
m $\otimes$ (an) = a(m $\otimes$ n)
(for all a $\in$ A, m $\in$ M and n $\in$ N ).
The module T is denoted M $\bigotimes$$_A$ N and is called the tensor product of
M and N over A.*

---

In the notes it is stated, as if obvious, that K is an A-submodule of L and that T = L/K is a module - but I just don't see how.

I also don't understand why the relations are satisfied - I try plugging in some arbitrary values l$_{m_1,n_1}$ etc. to try and prove the relations, but I have no idea how to manipulate these since to me they are just indexed l's which I can't do anything with.

Really appreciate any guidance you can give me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of the tensor product is its universal property, which is quite simple. What you are struggling with is the *construction* of the tensor product - this is something different. If you want to see a construction of the tensor product which avoids free modules at all, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291644).

$K$ is by definition a submodule, since it is defined as the submodule generated by some elements. Also, you should be already familiar with the general fact that a quotient of a module by a submodule is again a module. This is done exactly as in linear algebra with vector spaces. See [quotient module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_module). Recall that the basic idea of quotient is to make some elements zero. (The idea is not to compute with cosets - this is again just a construction which has no meaning at all.)

The idea behind the construction is that we want to compute with symbols $m \otimes n$ which become bilinear in each variable, for example $(m_1+m_2) \otimes n = m_1 \otimes n + m_2 \otimes n$, i.e. $(m_1 + m_2) \otimes n - m_1 \otimes n - m_2 \otimes n = 0$. For this, we consider the free module generated by symbols $(m,n)$ and just mod out the smallest submodule containing elements such as $(m_1+m_2,n)-(m_1,n)-(m_2,n)$ (and other ones). If $m \otimes n$ denotes the image of $(m,n)$, we have then $(m_1 + m_2) \otimes n - m_1 \otimes n - m_2 \otimes n = 0$ *by construction*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So let me see if I've understood correctly - the generators of K are chosen specially so that their image in L/K is the zero element of L/K (e.g. let k = l$_{m_1+m_2,n}$ - l$_{m_1,n}$ - l$_{m_2,n}$ $\in$ K. Then k + K $\in$ L/K equals K i.e. 0$_{L/K}$, so we can rearrange this element to make the relations satisfied)?

Comment: Yes, that's right.